# RamDrive com ram da placa de vídeo

Tags: r, desempenho

Utilizo a linguagem R para cálculos pesados de matrizes. Estou utilizando a gpu para ganho de desempenho, o que é fantástico mesmo.

Contudo, gostaria de dar mais um passo e despejar a matriz de 2gb de dados direto na ram da placa de vídeo

Ou talvez, criar um ramdrive com a ram da placa de vídeo que é ddr5

Isso seria possível?

Comment: Se fosse só o ramdrive, não sei se seria exatamente uma dúvida de programação, mas quando fala em despejar a matriz de dados para lá, a pergunta fica realmente interessante.

Comment: O R já roda e carrega na ram, com determinados pacotes daria para estender para usar o disco para paginar. A carga de uma matriz destas dimensões demora horrores, porque busca do disco e joga em uma variável.

Comment: A intensão aqui seria jogar em uma variável, mas a memória ram seria a da placa de vídeo. Isso porque os demais comandos de inversão de matrizes, etc serão com a gpu

Comment: A vantagem aqui é não utilizar a ram do pc e enviar direto para gpu, faltando apenas os comandos de execução

Comment: esse recurso não precisa existir em R, se existir em C posso chamar o código a partir do R

Comment: "esse recurso não precisa existir em R, se existir em C posso chamar o código a partir do R" Talvez seja interessante editar a pergunta e colocar tag de C, vai aumentar bastante o número de visualizações da pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Sim existe essa possibilidade em R, alis computação paralela vem dos primórdios no R, é só dar uma olhada na seção de *High-Performance and Parallel Computing with R* no CRAN, tais o [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) para agilizar.

Sim, você pode escrever em C e chamar no R se preferir, como esse exemplo:

```
#include 
#include <cufft.h>
/* This function is written for R to compute 1D FFT.
   n - [IN] the number of complex we want to compute
   inverse - [IN] set to 1 if use inverse mode
   h_idata_re - [IN] input data from host (R, real part)
   h_idata_im - [IN] input data from host (R, imaginary part)
   h_odata_re - [OUT] results (real) allocated by caller
   h_odata_im - [OUT] results (imaginary) allocated by caller
*/
extern "C"
void cufft(int *n, int *inverse, double *h_idata_re,
           double *h_idata_im, double *h_odata_re, double *h_odata_im)
{
  cufftHandle plan;
  cufftDoubleComplex *d_data, *h_data;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_data, sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex)*(*n));
  h_data = (cufftDoubleComplex *) malloc(sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex) * (*n));

  // Convert data to cufftDoubleComplex type
  for(int i=0; i< *n; i++) {
    h_data[i].x = h_idata_re[i];
    h_data[i].y = h_idata_im[i];
  }

  cudaMemcpy(d_data, h_data, sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex) * (*n), 
             cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  // Use the CUFFT plan to transform the signal in place.
  cufftPlan1d(&plan, *n, CUFFT_Z2Z, 1);
  if (!*inverse ) {
    cufftExecZ2Z(plan, d_data, d_data, CUFFT_FORWARD);
  } else {
    cufftExecZ2Z(plan, d_data, d_data, CUFFT_INVERSE);
  }

  cudaMemcpy(h_data, d_data, sizeof(cufftDoubleComplex) * (*n), 
  cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  // split cufftDoubleComplex to double array
  for(int i=0; i<*n; i++) {
    h_odata_re[i] = h_data[i].x;
    h_odata_im[i] = h_data[i].y;
  }

  // Destroy the CUFFT plan and free memory.
  cufftDestroy(plan);
  cudaFree(d_data);
  free(h_data);
}
```

Depois de fazer wrapper em R:

```
cufft1D <- function(x, inverse=FALSE)
{
  if(!is.loaded("cufft")) {
    dyn.load("cufft.so")
  }
  n <- length(x)
  rst <- .C("cufft",
  as.integer(n),
  as.integer(inverse),
  as.double(Re(z)),
  as.double(Im(z)),
  re=double(length=n),
  im=double(length=n))
  rst <- complex(real = rst[["re"]], imaginary = rst[["im"]])
  return(rst)
}
```

Não é tão simples assim, existem algumas configurações e algumas questões relacionadas a bibliotecas, mas isso ai em cima é só pra ter uma ideia. Aqui neste [link](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/accelerate-r-applications-cuda/) tem um belo tutorial e tb é a fonte de onde tirei as funções.

p.s.: uma matriz de 2 GB não é tão grande e pesada assim se usar as formas certas em seu algoritmo.